# Sql Server 2008 Installation?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Can I install and use sql server 2005 and 2008 in the same time on the same machine
because I have an old software that use SQL server 2005 and another new one that use Sql server 2008

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will be asked for an instance name during the installation of each one. Just give a different name for each instance.